# How do I make my code list all the possibilities of 2 dice being rolled using for loops?

Tags: javascript

*/Write a program that prints all possible dice rolls with 2 dice. To do so, you should use a double for loop. Hint: You can’t use i for both for loops./*

```
var SIDES_ON_DICE = 6;

for(var y = 1; y <=6; y++){
    println(y);
}
```

*/ I don't know how I would list all the possible dice rolls with for loops. More specifically, how would I go about solving this? I'm thinking I have to make it so my two variables for the 2 dice (lets call it x and y) have to increment in relation to each other. so for example, the dice rolls will be 1,1 then 1,2 until 1,6. then it goes to 2,1 etc etc. I'm thinking I need to increment the dice in relation to each other, so for example i make it so dice x increments by 1 every time dice y is equal to 6. How would I do this with for loops? Or is there a better way to go about solving this? thank you*/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: This looks like a homework question

Comment: I'm doing some codeacademy problems to improve. I wanted to get into coding but there arent any cs classes at my school so I started online programs to study.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how its done :

**This will list all the unique possibilities.**

```
var SIDES_ON_DICE = 6;

for(var x = 1; x <= SIDES_ON_DICE; x++){
   for(var y = x; y <= SIDES_ON_DICE; y++){
    println("x is " + x + " and y is " + y);
   }
}
```

---

**With all possibilities:**

```
var SIDES_ON_DICE = 6;

for(var x = 1; x <= SIDES_ON_DICE; x++){
   for(var y = 1; y <= SIDES_ON_DICE; y++){
    println("First Dice is " + x + " and Second Dice is " + y);
   }
}
```

Comment: the biggest problem I'm having with the code is that when i list the two variables like an ordered pair, it gives me an error (Uncaught Error: You should pass exactly 1 argument to println). I tried doing a code similar to that but it didnt allow me, so I have no idea what to do to get around that...

Comment: you are using java ? or javascript ?

Comment: I'm using javascript

Comment: @KushyPoo, try now.

Comment: thank you so much! so basically, the x and y for loops will be the same, just within eachother so they can be in relation to eachother. for future reference, how could I list the two values as an ordered pair without the "first dice is" and "second dice is"?

Comment: println( x +" "+ y);